# Ways to allow 3rd party content in our site

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xss

Let's say I want to display content from some other domain on my site.
So I use an iframe on my page and say

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" />
```

Now I guess because of things like Same Origin policy and all, this might not work.

I just wanted to know what are the ways by which I can display 3rd party domain content on my site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide something like a server side proxy and redirect all requests over it

```
<iframe src="webContentProxy/url/encoded(http://www.google.com)" />
```

The workflow/architecture would be as the following

- webContentProxy/url/{URL} is some controller on *your* server it takes an {url} as parameter in some form, loads the content of the url server side and streams it back to the client
- The iframe is loaded from *your* server through the controller

Means, the browser only communicates with your server and your server communicates with the foreign server. This way you also can handle some more like authentication or url rewrite.

Comment: @testndtv Added a litte more description. From principle it's like a simple proxy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, you can use an `iframe` so long as you do not wish to modify the page inside. An exception to this is if the site you are trying to show in your iframe is preventing you from doing this. There are framebusting techniques around this but I wouldn't recommend it.

The same origin policy is a way of allowing one site to call javascript in the site within the iframe. For security reasons you cannot do this, for example on google.com